# Pig Latin Translator won’t write results?

Tags: javascript, html, latin

I’m trying to write a pig latin translator, but my webpage keeps displaying `undefined`, and it can’t read from the textarea. The html looks okay, but the text from the textarea that the end user needs inputs is not displayed correctly. I tried changing the textarea’s text by using `.textContent`, `value`, and many others.

```js
var textarea = document.getElementById("piglatin");
var button = document.getElementById("click_to_translate");
var translation = document.getElementById("translation");
var toPigLatin = function(str){
    str=str.replace(/([^aeiou]*)([aeiou])(\w+)/, "$2$3$1ay");
};
button.onclick = function(){
    translation.innerHTML = toPigLatin(textarea.textContent);
};
```

```html
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <script src="pig_latin.js"></script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <h1 id="translation">
                PigLatin Translator!
            </h1>
            <textarea rows="1" cols="30" id="piglatin"></textarea>
            <button type="button" id="click_to_translate">Translate</button>
        </div>
    </body>
    
</html>
```

I’m about to give up at this point, and it would be appreciated if someone could help.

Comment: `textarea.value` See [HTMLTextAreaElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTextAreaElement).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were two issues: The function `toPigLatin` should `return` the appropriate result, instead of setting `str=...`. Also, the value of a text area is `textarea.value`.

```js
var textarea = document.getElementById("piglatin");
var button = document.getElementById("click_to_translate");
var translation = document.getElementById("translation");
var toPigLatin = function(str){
    return str.replace(/([^aeiou]*)([aeiou])(\w+)/, "$2$3$1ay");
};
button.onclick = function(){
    translation.innerHTML = toPigLatin(textarea.value);
};
```

```html
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <script src="pig_latin.js"></script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <h1 id="translation">
                PigLatin Translator!
            </h1>
            <textarea rows="1" cols="30" id="piglatin"></textarea>
            <button type="button" id="click_to_translate">Translate</button>
        </div>
    </body>
    
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because your `toPigLatin` function doesn't return anything, it just reassigns the variable copied to the parameter. Use this line instead:

```
return str.replace(/([^aeiou]*)([aeiou])(\w+)/, "$2$3$1ay");
```

Also, you have to use `textarea.value`.

```js
var textarea = document.getElementById("piglatin");
var button = document.getElementById("click_to_translate");
var translation = document.getElementById("translation");
var toPigLatin = function(str) {
  return str.replace(/([^aeiou]*)([aeiou])(\w+)/, "$2$3$1ay");
};
button.onclick = function() {
  translation.innerHTML = toPigLatin(textarea.value);
};
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <h1 id="translation">
                PigLatin Translator!
            </h1>
  <textarea rows="1" cols="30" id="piglatin"></textarea>
  <button type="button" id="click_to_translate">Translate</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because if you step through it your

```
textarea.textContent
```

Is not the value you need `textarea.value` instead

Also you need to return the data in your function.

```js
var textarea = document.getElementById("piglatin");
var button = document.getElementById("click_to_translate");
var translation = document.getElementById("translation");
var toPigLatin = function(str){
    return str.replace(/([^aeiou]*)([aeiou])(\w+)/, "$2$3$1ay");
};
button.onclick = function(){
    translation.innerHTML = toPigLatin(textarea.value);
};
```

```html
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <script src="pig_latin.js"></script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <h1 id="translation">
                PigLatin Translator!
            </h1>
            <textarea rows="1" cols="30" id="piglatin"></textarea>
            <button type="button" id="click_to_translate">Translate</button>
        </div>
    </body>
    
</html>
```